# Amazon MWS - Access to Orders.ListOrders is denied

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I need to fetch the Amazon Marketplace orders with the PHP API.
I have my access tokens for the Amazon MWS scratchpad, but each time I get an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access to Orders.ListOrders is denied</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestID>841e86f2-aa88-4d71-83e3-4ed3c3695fb1</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I don't understand what needs to be done to make it work.

Thx

Comment: Do you check the permission yet?

Comment: yes, but I must be missing one. but I don't know where to find it.

Comment: I really don't understand anything. This documentation is not clear to me. 
I have a developer account, but when I want to authorize myself in seller central, I have the error : 
"This Developer is not currently eligible for new authorizations." (MD9000)